# crash when replacing the fragment with a fragment containing a viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I created a HomeFragment containing a viewpager, and I added it to the MainActivity, It worked fine. But when I clicked to go to another fragment like BucketFragment and then clicked to go back to homefragment, it crashed, throwing a nullpointer exception.

Here's the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private HomeFragment mHomeFragment;
    private LikeFragment mLikeFragment;
    private BucketFragment mBucketFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    // add the fragment content
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
        mHomeFragment = (HomeFragment) fragment;
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    Fragment currentFragment = null;
    Intent intent = null;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            if (mHomeFragment == null) {
                mHomeFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
            }
            currentFragment = mHomeFragment;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_like:
            if (mLikeFragment == null) {
                mLikeFragment = LikeFragment.newInstance();
            }
            currentFragment = mLikeFragment;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_bucket:
            if (mBucketFragment == null) {
                mBucketFragment = BucketFragment.newInstance();
            }
            currentFragment = mBucketFragment;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_help:
            intent = HelpActivity.newIntent(this);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_feedback:
            intent = FeedBackActivity.newIntent(this);
            break;
        default:break;
    }


    if (currentFragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, currentFragment)
                .commit();
        setTitle(item.getTitle());
    } else {
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

Here's HomeFragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final int NUM_CATOGARY = 2;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    public static HomeFragment newInstance() {
        return new HomeFragment();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

   mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
   TabLayout tab = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tab);
   tab.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

   FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();

   mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
       @Override
       public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           switch (position) {
               case 0:
                   return PopularFragment.newInstance();
               case 1:
                   return RecentFragment.newInstance();
           }
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public int getCount() {
           return NUM_CATOGARY;
       }

       @Nullable
       @Override
       public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
           switch (position) {
               case 0:
                   return getResources().getText(R.string.tab_popular);
               case 1:
                   return getResources().getText(R.string.tab_recent);
           }
           return null;
       }
   });

   return v;
}
}
```

and `fragment_home.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

when I click to return to homefragment, it throws a runtime exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.util.SparseArray.get(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment(FragmentManager.java:902)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.restoreState(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:216)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onRestoreInstanceState(ViewPager.java:1455)
    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:14956)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3253)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3259)
    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:14934)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:396)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1445)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2239)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5770)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: there is structure problem I guess since you are not adding your fragments to backstack in main activity and assume it to give the functionality of backpress for now it will just replace the existing fragment and only one fragment is there in backstack always.

Comment: Thanks, It helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this piece of code

```
if (currentFragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, currentFragment)
                .commit();
        setTitle(item.getTitle());
    }
```

Replace method works as remove+add and this means you have no fragment in stack to return to, so you should either put `add` instead  or add this line `.addToBackStack(null);` before `.commit`. It will put your operation to backstack and then you can go back using back button

Answer (score 0):

if you'll use `addToBackStack(null)` for your `supportFragmentManager` your each fragment will be reload when its start so `fragment` won't be keep on stack.

i have changed `childFragmentManager` with `supportFragmentManager` in `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and its worked.